# INNER JOIN on UPDATE with WHERE updating every record in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update a single record and return the email of the owner of the updated record by doing INNER JOIN de ID of the `createdby` which links to the `users` table.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE requests
SET statusid = 2
FROM requests AS r
INNER JOIN users
ON r.createdby = users.id
WHERE r.id =10
RETURNING r.id, users.email;
```

But this will update every record instead of using the `WHERE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you do not repeat the table being updated in the `FROM`.  So:

```
UPDATE requests r
    SET statusid = 2
    FROM users u
    WHERE r.createdby = u.id AND r.id =10
RETURNING r.id, u.email;
```